# Where is that post describing how many points you need to do what?

Tags: support

Where is that post describing how many points you need to do what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the [FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), linked (as "faq") at the top of (almost) every page?

> Amass enough reputation points and
>   Stack Overflow will allow you to go
>   beyond simply asking and answering
>   questions:
>
> - 15   Vote up
> - 15   Flag offensive
> - 50   Leave comments
> - 100  Vote down (costs 1 rep), edit community wiki posts
> - 200  Reduced advertising
> - 250  Vote to close or reopen your questions, create new tags
> - 500  Retag questions
> - 2000 Edit other people's posts
> - 3000 Vote to close or reopen any questions
> - 10000 Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

(note that the numbers may vary between sites; I've used stackoverflow for the example, but just click "faq" on the site you choose)

Answer (score 1):

[Here it is.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)

In the future, if there are any questions you have about how SO works, you can first go to the search box in the upper right corner of the page and type `faq`. This will show you [all the posts tagged as FAQs on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). There is also one large parent FAQ that links to most of the others: [How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

Comment: You'll need to surround the tag with [] - i.e. type `[faq]` for it to do a tag based search

Comment: @Chris, not really in this case; as one of top tags `faq` is autoconverted to tag search. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/